# How To Detect Red Color In OpenCV Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, computer-vision, opencv3.1

I am trying to detect red color from the video that's being taken from my webcam. The following code example given below is taken from [OpenCV Documentation.](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html) 
The code is given below:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):

    # Take each frame
    _, frame = cap.read()

    # Convert BGR to HSV
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # define range of blue color in HSV
    lower_blue = np.array([110,50,50])
    upper_blue = np.array([130,255,255])

    # Threshold the HSV image to get only blue colors
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)

    # Bitwise-AND mask and original image
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask)

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
    cv2.imshow('res',res)
    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The line `lower_blue = np.array([110,50,50])` has the lower range Blue HSV value and the line `upper_blue = np.array([130,255,255])` has the higher range Blue HSV value. I have looked for the upper value and lower value of Red color on internet but I couldn't find it. It would be very helpful if anyone could tell the HSV value of Red for OpenCV (OpenCV H value ranges from 0 - 179). 
Thanks a lot for help (In Advance).

I have also tried running the following to find the range of Red but I was unable to pick proper value maybe. What I tried was this(for red):

```
>>> green = np.uint8([[[0,255,0 ]]])
>>> hsv_green = cv2.cvtColor(green,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
>>> print hsv_green
[[[ 60 255 255]]]
```

This was also taken from OpenCV documentation.
Please tell me or help me find the RANGE of RED COLOR for OpenCV.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737613/image-of-hsv-color-wheel-for-opencv) -- you can use the color wheel there and divide the value (in the 0-360 range) to find out the Hue value (as noted in the accepted answer). You can also take a look at [this example](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2015/05/08/detect-red-circles-image-using-opencv/). To briefly answer your question, red is around the 0 and 180 values (since colors "wrap around")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV better detection of red color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32522989/opencv-better-detection-of-red-color)

Comment: I don't really understand that how do I get the S and V values. Can you please explain? Thanks a lot (in advance)! @Miki

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running the same code for red seems to work:

```
>>> red = numpy.uint8([[[0,0,255]]])
>>> hsv_red = cv2.cvtColor(red,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
>>> print(hsv_red)
[[[  0 255 255]]]
```

And then you can try different colors that appear reddish. Beware that the red range includes both numbers slightly greater than 0 and numbers slightly smaller than 179 (e.g. `red = numpy.uint8([[[0,31,255]]])` results in `[[[  4 255 255]]]` whereas `red = numpy.uint8([[[31,0,255]]])` results in `[[[176 255 255]]]`.

Comment: In the [doc](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html#how-to-find-hsv-values-to-track) from the site linked above, you have the values `[[[ 0 255 255]]]` that you plug into the short "equation" to get the upper and lower bounds for that color. " you take `[H-10, 100,100]` and `[H+10, 255, 255]` as lower bound and upper bound respectively". This would leave you with a lower bound of `[ 0, 100, 100]` and an upper bound `[10, 255, 255]` for red, but you can make that `20` for a better range.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a program to determine color you need by choosing the 6 arrays parameters.(work on Opencv 3.2).
You chose your image or a "color range barre" input image and you move cursors and see which arrays values are the ones you need to isolate your color!
[Color range program screen pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8B5gH.jpg)

here is the code:(can easily be adapted for video input).
image.jpg->(your image)
color_bar.jpg->(any image you want just to display a windows,try anything)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def nothing(x):
    pass

def main():

    window_name='color range parameter'
    cv2.namedWindow(window_name)
    # Create a black image, a window
    im = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
    cb = cv2.imread('color_bar.jpg')
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    print ('lower_color = np.array([a1,a2,a3])')
    print ('upper_color = np.array([b1,b2,b3])')


    # create trackbars for color change
    cv2.createTrackbar('a1',window_name,0,255,nothing)
    cv2.createTrackbar('a2',window_name,0,255,nothing)
    cv2.createTrackbar('a3',window_name,0,255,nothing)

    cv2.createTrackbar('b1',window_name,150,255,nothing)
    cv2.createTrackbar('b2',window_name,150,255,nothing)
    cv2.createTrackbar('b3',window_name,150,255,nothing)

    while(1):
        a1 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('a1',window_name)
        a2 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('a2',window_name)
        a3 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('a3',window_name)

        b1 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('b1',window_name)
        b2 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('b2',window_name)
        b3 = cv2.getTrackbarPos('b3',window_name)

        # hsv hue sat value
        lower_color = np.array([a1,a2,a3])
        upper_color = np.array([b1,b2,b3])
        mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_color, upper_color)
        res = cv2.bitwise_and(im, im, mask = mask)

        cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
        cv2.imshow('res',res)
        cv2.imshow('im',im)
        cv2.imshow(window_name,cb)

        k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        if k == 27:         # wait for ESC key to exit
            break
        elif k == ord('s'): # wait for 's' key to save and exit
            cv2.imwrite('Img_screen_mask.jpg',mask)
            cv2.imwrite('Img_screen_res.jpg',res)
            break


    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


#Run Main
if __name__ == "__main__" :
    main()
```

Comment: can you share the color_bar image?